# Mule exception handling

Tags: exception, mule

i am using a Mule Webservice consumer to call a soap service .The service returns a string message instead of Soapresponse or soap fault and throws an error and landed in exception handling part.

i need how to call a another flow based on the message received in exception handling ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
Why are you getting that exception, which processor is throwing it?
Can you paste your XML code?

Comment: i am using ws consumer...endpoint service returns plain text message like "Login failed" instead of wrapped in a soap fault or soap response and goes to exception block.In the exception block i need to check if the message contains "Login Failed" if so i need to call a flow service again for further processing ex to get session token and call the service again

Answer (score 0):

1) Set up the flow you want to execute when an exception is caught.

2) Inside the exception block (of the flow calling the service) - put a "flow reference" shape to call the flow outside the exception block you create in step 1.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.....i tried putting a flow ref inside exception block..but the deployment fails stating circular reference..

Comment: I know, thats why i asked you what are you trying to achieve, in the first place... :)

Comment: You could use a "Choice" to check if the value is "Login Failed" and call the appropriate flow using a Flow Reference from inside your exception block.

Comment: Ganesh, did you create a separate flow to handle the Login Failed scenario, and call that in the <catch-exception-strategy> of your first flow? It might help if you added some of your code to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response...yes i follwed the same...inside seperate catch exception strategy in the same app i tried to match the error responce in choice and  i tried referencing another flow also in the same app ..but deployment failed due to circular referencing